# C# awaiting group of tasks, but returning objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Just a quick question. I believe this is just a quick syntax question. Below I'm sending out 3 threads and for testing multi-threading I just have the methods returning an int, not using them for anything.

Now, I am trying to go further with this and return a datatable with each thread sent out. However, I obviously can't say 'datatable dt = tasks.Add(....etc.'

So how would I send out all 3 threads at the same time and get the 3 datatables returned to me? Would I use something other than an array?

Edit- I think I'm not explaining myself well I apologize. All I'm doing is each method( nrx.nzrxin, ni.nzinputins) returns a datatable. I just don't know the syntax for sending the method out in a thread. Usually you would do 'datatable dt = nrz.nzrxins'. How do you do that with a task?

Thanks,

```
NZInput NI = new NZInput();
NZOutput NO = new NZOutput();
NZRX NRX = new NZRX();


List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(3);

tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => NRX.nzrxins()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => NI.nzinputins()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => NO.nzoutputins()));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily collect all results by using [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you want a synchronous version: `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result`.

It is worth spending some time to get to know all the common TPL helper methods.

Answer (score 3):

Get the results.  Simple.

```
NZInput NI = new NZInput();
NZOutput NO = new NZOutput();
NZRX NRX = new NZRX();


var tasks = new[]{
    Task.Run(() => NRX.nzrxins()),
    Task.Run(() => NI.nzinputins()),
    Task.Run(() => NO.nzoutputins())),
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

var nrxResult = tasks[0].Result;
var niResult = tasks[1].Result;
var noResult = tasks[2].Result;
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Check the Result property of each task once they have finished. Note that exceptions will bubble up at this point.